# Simple script doesn't run

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have five images in a folder of my computer and I'm trying to create a script that display an image on the screen and when I click a button the image changes.

The JavaScript code:

```
function cambiaimagen()
{
var i=1;
var direcciones = new            
    Array("imagen1.jpg","imagen2.jpg","imagen3.jpg","imagen4.jpg","imagen5.jpg");
var vusr = document.getElementById('imgs').value;
document.getElementById('imgs').innerHTML = vusr;
}
```

The HTML code:

```
<div id="contenedor">

<div id="img">
<img id="imgs" src="imagen1.jpg"/>
</div>

<button type="button">Anterior</button>
<button type="button" onclick = 'cambiaimagen()'>Siguiente</button>

</div>
```

When I run the script I watch the image 1 and the buttons. But when I click `Siguiente` button I don't watch the following image of array `direcciones`.

How can I watch it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your previous JavaScript code with this:

```
var cnt = 1;
var direcciones = new Array("imagen1.jpg","imagen2.jpg","imagen3.jpg","imagen4.jpg","imagen5.jpg");
function cambiaimagen(){
    if(cnt != direcciones.length - 1){
        cnt++;
    }else{
        cnt = 1;
    }
    document.getElementById('imgs').src = direcciones[cnt];
}
```

If the image names are in sequential number order (as they are in your example), you could use the following instead:

```
var cnt = 1;
var imgCnt = 5;
function cambiaimagen(){
    if(cnt != imgCnt){
        cnt++;
    }else{
        cnt = 1;
    }
    document.getElementById('imgs').src = "imagen" + cnt + "2.jpg";
}
```

Which I believe is a better method because there is no array with repetitive contents.

Comment: I'm using Firefox and there are no JavaScript errors. Wnen I run the script I only watch the image and the buttons. When I click one button the image doesn't change.

Comment: Yes. Now it works. I was typed the code wrongly. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var direcciones = ["imagen1.jpg","imagen2.jpg","imagen3.jpg","imagen4.jpg","imagen5.jpg"];
var cnt = 0;
function cambiaimagen(){
document.getElementById("imgs").src = direcciones[(++cnt)%direcciones.length];
}
```

Comment: You should probably explain what you're doing, rather than just post code.

Comment: I think it's just one more way of doing the answer anyone else would give.